# How to update timestamp column so that every row in a table would have a random value?

Tags: mysql, sql

What I want to achieve is a random timestamp value for every row in a table but beginning from some predefined time, like in this pseudo code:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `time_column` = RANDOM_TIMESTAMP() NOT LESS THAN NOW() - 1 HOUR;
```

Currently I do this and I get the same `timestamp` value for all rows.

```
UPDATE `table` SET `time` = NOW();

id | time_column
--------------
1  | 100
2  | 100
3  | 100
```

Is this operation possible with MySQL only? In one `UPDATE` query?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
set @n := 0;
update `table`
    set time = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR + INTERVAL (@n := @n + 1) SECOND);
```

Initial approach by [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff)

```
set @n := 0;
update `table`
    set time = (now() - interval 1 hour) + interval (@n := @n + 1) second;
```

Initial approach is also important to know.

Comment: Added the UNIX_TIMESTAMP because it's needed to convert DATETIME into a int.